# Save data into Model and get data from Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Hi I'm building a Webshop with a cart and checkout function. And I want to save data into a database.

Here are my **models**:
This is the model I want to save the data in:

```
class MessageItem(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    mItem = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    mQuantity = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)  # Could also be an Integer!
    mOrderItem = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

After I did that I want to call the data in another view and pass it into a **sendmail()** message variable. Does anyone know how I could do that?

Here are my other **models**:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)  # Nicht nötig
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is my **View**: I Want to save: item.product.name, item.quantity and items into the model.

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def cart(request):
    # If user logged in or not (Handling orders in cart)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
        for item in items:
            SMES = item.product.name, str(item.quantity), items
            print(SMES)

    context = {'items': items, 'order': order, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
```

And this is the other view with the Sendmail() function:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        message_name = request.POST['message-name']
        message_email = request.POST['message-email']
        message = request.POST['message']

        message_to_send = str(message)

        # send an email
        send_mail(
            'message from ' + message_name,  # subject
            message_to_send,  # message
            message_email,  # from email
            ['jeampo@outlook.de'],  # To Email
        )
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

your question is not fully understood. Do I understand correctly that:
in your for-loop in the cart view you want to save each orderitem of the incompleted customer's order in a MessageItem instance?

```
for item in items:
        item_data = {'customer':customer,
                     'mItem':item.product.name,
                     'mQuantity':str(item.quantity),
                     'mOrderItem': '',} #Not sure what you want with items
        message_item = MessageItem(**item_data)
        message_item.save()
```

items is currently a queryset your looping over, and mOrderItem needs a string. So that one doesn't match yet.

I'm not sure if I'm getting the goal of your MessageItem object. Currently each time you call it a new MessageItem is created for each exisiting OrderItem in scope. create_or_update is probably what you want in this situation? Please clarify your goal to better understand the question at hand.